# Read PDF from Blob storage and convert it into text

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a problem for read PDf file from azure blob storage and convert it into text format.
    Is there any method available in C#.net to read the PDf file. Or any 3ed party free dll available.
      thanks in advance

Comment: Google talking about some PDF reader or converter toll(3ed party)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pdf reading and manipulating [Itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) libraby is fine.

For extracting text from pdf see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET)

Comment: Good idea. But i think some license issue. What you think about that..Thanks

Comment: Itextsharp is opensource and free for use. but not for commercial use.

Comment: Md Kamruzzaman Pallob : Yes that is a problem. Because i want to use it in some of my latest project. So If you know about some free tool.